# Reload configuration data without server application/server

Tags: java, web-services, jenkins, restful-architecture, stackato

I have a requirement to reload a configuration file dynamically without restarting the server.

Details with example:

- I have a restful web service deployed in **stackato server**.
- I am using **Jenkins pipeline** to build and deploy in the server.
- I need to maintain a configurable data say **TTL = 60** anywhere which can be configured, and upon configuring the deployed WAR will reload the data **without restarting the application/server**. The data will be dynamically reloaded.

This is very important for me and I need help desperately. Will keep updating this post based on the comments,suggestion and questions.

Thanks

Comment: Put it in a database.

Comment: My project dont have a database.